# how to convert js widget to amp component

Tags: javascript, widget, amp-html

I have widget written in pure Javascript.
On load it creates a button at the bottom of the page. 
clicking the button creates on iframe and loads my chatbot site in it.

I have small snippet that loads the widget's js and css into the dom.

Here is a sample usage :

```
<script>(function (w, d, s, l, i) {
    w[l]    = i;
    var f   = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], j = d.createElement(s);
    j.async = true;
    j.src   = 'https://intaker.co/dist/chat-widget.min.js';
    f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
})(window, document, 'script', 'SU5UQUtFUl9DSEFUX1VSTA==', 'aHR0cHM6Ly9hdHRvcm5leS5jaGF0L2ZhcmhhZA==');</script>
```

Now , I need to make this compatible with [AMP](https://amp.dev) pages. I have been reading the docs and made a component. But it seems that its not possible to load the widgets external script into the component!!!

So do I have to rewrite the entire widget as a AMP component?? has any one has experience converting a widget like this to AMP component ??

I really don't want to keep 2 versions of the same code :(

UPDATE: I have not created any component yet, just the getting started helloworld sample https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/creating-your-first-amp-component/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0 , I could not figure out how to embed my external script into this component (which seems not possible!).

UPDATE2: I think i can use [amp-script](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-script/?format=websites) but I am not sure
UPDATE3: :( NOPE `amp-script` is experimental, can't use it in production module

Comment: Could you provide the code where you attempted to create an AMP version of this widget?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier I didn't go far, just created the hellowordl sample, I was trying to just create this snippet and load the main script inside it :)

Answer (score 0):

Your options are

- custom amp-component
- [amp-iframe](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-iframe/#sandbox)

**Custom component**

With the custom amp component, you can explore extending the amp-iframe and load the content of your site within that iframe. Alternatively you can just build it from scratch, pulling out the necessary logic from your existing widget's JS and understanding the life cycle of an amp-component and placing the proper logic where need be. Note that the benefits of going this route is that others can use your component on their site, if this is something that is desired or possible.

**AMP Iframe**

Just load your widget in an AMP iframe.

Comment: An update. amp-script is now available for general use. https://blog.amp.dev/2019/08/21/amp-script-amp-heart-js/

Comment: yeah saw that and tried it, not really on option, so many restrictions, got it to work up to a point where it just broke and stopped , gana try iframe now

Comment: I see. If you have time I'd like to know more about the obstacles you've encountered with amp-script and your current progress with amp-iframe. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find anything in the primevue docs about how to accomplish this so this is what I ended up with.

I can't tell if your menu is in a child component. If it you can simply make a computed property that adds the appointment prop to the command

```js
props: {
  appointment: Object,
},
computed: {
  items() {
    return [{
      label: 'Reschedule',
      command: this.reschedule(this.appointment)
    }];
  },
},
methods: {
  reschedule(appointment) {
    // appointment & appointment id available here
  },
}
```

and just bind the menu items

```html
<Menu ref="menu" :model="items" :popup="true" />
```

---

If your menu is in the same component as your table data & datatable component you can do a computed property that is a dictionary with id lookup.

```js
computed: {
  appointmentMenuItemsDictionary() {
    return this.appointments.reduce((acc, appointment) => {
      acc[appointment.id] = [{
        label: 'Reschedule',
        command: this.reschedule(appointment)
      }];

      return acc;
    }, {});
  },
},
methods: {
  reschedule(appointment) {
    // appointment & appointment id available here
  },
}
```

Now to bind it to each row

```html
<-- Assuming your menu is within a v-for loop (or within the DataTable component) -->
<Menu
  ref="menu"
  :model="appointmentMenuItemsDictionary[appointment.id]"
  :popup="true"
/>
```